# My cloned Chef server has a problems with syncronising of recipies

Tags: chef

I have inherit a complex company cloud based server system with several Nodes that is using Chef for the setup of the different nodes.

Chef + Ironfan + Berksshelf are the most important elements on the Chef server.

For a redundant system have I cloned the fully working chef server to another cloud instance. *( =full backup and copied nearly all files + manual work on some config files + chef-server-ctl reconfigure + reboots)*

The Cloned server has a different name/ different IP and it looked already perfect on the first view.

- The Web Interface is up and working.
- I could launch/bootstrap/sync/kill Cloud nodes with the Ironfan commands.
- I was able to move some instances from another Chef server to this one.

But I am facing a nasty problem during the "kick" command with newly created nodes.

The client node tries to download some recipe from the chef server and the download is failing.

error message:

```
euca-10-130-130-10.eucalyptus.escloc59.eecloud.xxx-net.net [2015-11-10T16:01:00+02:00] INFO: Loading cookbooks [shell_application@0.1.0, apt@2.6.0, mongodb@0.11.0, collectd@1.0.0, catagis-monitoring@0.0.0, java@1.29.0, xfs@1.1.0, silverware@3.5.6, volumes@3.1.2, users@1.1.2, cloud_libs@0.1.0, hosts@0.1.1, ntp@1.7.0, emacs@0.9.1, zsh@1.0.1, motd@3.2.6, build-essential@2.1.3]
euca-10-130-130-10.eucalyptus.escloc59.eecloud.xxx-net.net Synchronizing Cookbooks:
euca-10-130-130-10.eucalyptus.escloc59.eecloud.xxx-net.net [2015-11-10T16:01:00+02:00] ERROR: Server returned error for https://euca-10-156-11-32.eucalyptus.escloc26.eecloud.xxx-net.net/bookshelf/organization-00000000000000000000000000000000/checksum-0bd386798d6b692c8ee93cf03d54e8cd?AWSAccessKeyId=db31f0c5d2a32cd283b92fa8593f12124decf74d&Expires=1447164960&Signature=HLOne/z1M7/M6WeHDgNWvr4q%2BmE%3D, retrying 1/5 in 3s
euca-10-130-130-10.eucalyptus.escloc59.eecloud.xxx-net.net
euca-10-130-130-10.eucalyptus.escloc59.eecloud.xxx-net.net [2015-11-10T16:01:00+02:00] ERROR: Server returned error for https://euca-10-156-11-32.eucalyptus.escloc26.eecloud.xxx-net.net/bookshelf/organization-00000000000000000000000000000000/checksum-2414583f86c9eb68bdbb0be391939341?AWSAccessKeyId=db31f0c5d2a32cd283b92fa8593f12124decf74d&Expires=1447164960&Signature=SDtiucg02gmuCYBAWxurNSN4xKk%3D, retrying 1/5 in 4s
```

I looked for the different ID's and found some of them.

AWSAccessKeyId is is the correct access id for the bookshelf.

The "organization" and "checksum" have I found in folder /var/opt/chef-server/bookshelf/data/bookshelf.

Expires is a Unix time stamp and fits with the server time.
I found nothing about the Signature.

I am despairing on this problem since 2 days now and made no visible progress. What is going on on the server and where can I see more details?
Is a wrong signature the reason for the problem?

Maybe somebody can help me with some hints.